# Accessing query of query loop block from another block, gutenberg wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating a custom block inside a plugin. It's a drop down selector of categories for posts. I'm simply trying to update the query of a query loop block on the same page. However I'm not sure how to access the query of the query loop block.

I've tried the above however getting the blockId of the block doesn't seem to be possible on the front end. Does anyone know how i can reference the query loop block from a front end js file?

plugin.php

```
  function tapacode_selector_ajax_callback() {

    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'wp-tapacode-nonce' ) ) {
        die ( 'Busted!' );
    }

    $category = intval( $_POST['category']);
    $query_args = array(
        'cat' => $category
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    wp_send_json( $query->posts );
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tapacode_selector', 'tapacode_selector_ajax_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tapacode_selector', 'tapacode_selector_ajax_callback' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'ajax-selector-script', plugins_url( '/selector.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-editor', 'wp-element', 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-selector-script' );

    // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-selector-script', 'ajax_object',
            array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp-tapacode-nonce' )
            ) );
}
```

another plugin.php file

```
    <p <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
    
<?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>

</p>
```

selector.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setupCategorySelector, false);

function setupCategorySelector() {
    document.getElementById('cat').onchange = function () {
        // if value is category id
        if (this.value !== '-1') {
            if (typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.data) {
                const blockId = document.querySelector('.wp-block-tapacode-category-selector').getAttribute('data-block-id');
                const queryBlock = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlock(blockId);
                queryBlock.setAttributes({ categories: this.value });
                queryBlock.update();
            }
```